# Paperclip Downloading PDF Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been searching around and have found answers to my question, although cant seem to figure out one detail. I am using Paperclip gem to upload/download files and I am able to upload/download pdf's. The problem I am having is that when I click download, it only downloads the most recently uploaded pdf.

I want it to obviously download the pdf for the right document, instead of downloading the most recent one.

This is the code I've used to display the document title/download link:

`<%= document.title %> <%= link_to "Download", Document.last.pdf.url(:original, false) %>`

I'm pretty sure I would have to change the `.last.pdf.url....` to something else, I'm just not sure what to change it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a bit of a play around and figured it out myself. To anybody in the future seeing this all I did was modify the `link_to` to:

`<%= link_to "Download", document.pdf(:original, false) %>`

Getting rid of the `.last` and `.url` worked

Comment: I was going to post this answer now but you figured that out on your own. :)

Comment: Emu, while i've got you, would you know how to remove the timestamp from the download link? currently it's showing: `http://localhost:3000/system/documents/pdfs/000/000/005/original/The_Search_For_Better_Health_Notes.pdf?1468580996` but I would like to remove the numbers after the question mark. Do you know how?

Comment: there is an option `has_attached_file` where you can set `use_timestamp` to `false`